# in python, using in, get specific elements

Tags: python, list

I want to do something like this, but in python :

select * from [list] where [element at index n] = 'hello'

So far, I have this

```
    cells = [' ','hello',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
    emptySpots = []

    for s in range(len(cells)):
        if cells[s] == 'hello':
            emptySpots.append(s)
```

This gives me a list of the indexes of the cells with 'hello' in them, but I bet theres a more straightforeward (pythonesque) way to do this.

What would be nice is a one liner that just returns the count of the number of elements in cells that equal ' '.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is confusing. Your code does not get the indexes of the empty cells but of the element `hello`.

It seems you have two questions in one?

If you really want to get the number of "empty cells" like you claim in your last sentence, you can use `list.count`:

```
empty_spots = cells.count(' ')
```

Comment: There are two unrelated questions in the post.  I answered the first one, you answered the second one.

Comment: Ya, I sorta did ask in a confusing manner, sorry. Basically, my problem could be solved by selecting either the empty or non empty cells. I was unaware count() could work the way you showed, and from there I was able to get it to do what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to return a list of matching elements from a list (the title being "in python, using in, get specific elements"), or if you wanted to count all occurrences of them. You can use `filter` or a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to return matching elements from a list, and then call `len` on the result to count the number of times it occurs. If all you care about is finding the number of times an item occurs in a list `list.count` is the best approach.

`len(filter(lambda x: 'hello' == x, cells))`

`len([x for x in cells if x == 'hello'])`

And as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904912/in-python-using-in-get-specific-elements/5904929#5904929) (definitely the nicest way if you just wanted to count them!):
`cells.count(' ')`

Here's a simple bench of list comprehension vs filter:

```
% python -m timeit -s "data = ['hello' for x in range(100000)]" "[x for x in data if x == 'hello']"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.97 msec per loop
% python -m timeit -s "data = ['hello' for x in range(100000)]" "filter(lambda x: x == 'hello', data)"
100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 msec per loop
```

Comment: This one does not return the indices.  Please read the question again.

Comment: I thought he just wanted to count a recurring item in the list.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ok fair enough, but the OP may have explained his question incorrectly since his code does not return the keys.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I you down-voted, IMHO, the question is not clear enough to donw-vote, plus @zeekay updated his answer.

Comment: Well, the title is "in python, using in, get specific elements". That is what I thought he was after originally. Either way, good to know filter/list comprehensions.

Comment: All answers were educational. Im very new to python, and now have new branches to explore. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

```
[i for i in range(len(cells)) if cells[i] == "hello"]
```

or

```
[i for i, s in enumerate(cells) if s == "hello"]
```

Comment: O man, this is new to me, will have to play with this syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
cells = [' ','hello',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
matches = map(lambda x: x if cells[x] == 'hello' else False, range(len(cells)))
emptySpots = filter(lambda x: x == False, matches)
```